# Importing Salesforce .xlsx into Power BI

Tags: salesforce, powerbi, dax

if I import an .xlsx file from Salesforce into Power BI, there are instances where there are merged rows (number may vary) for a particular record.

Essentially there are merged rows that appear as one row and when one tries to import this data, the field will show it as 'Blank' when in fact it is non-empty.

Here is an example:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=31165804604333631590

How would I write the DAX query for this? Is this the best route?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the query using Power Query, and use `Table.FillDown` to fill the blanks.

For example:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Temp\Salesforce.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Promoted Headers",{"Vendor", "Shipping City"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

Comment: What's the difference between writing the query and just Fill->Down?